# Innertube patch don't seal for long

Tags: innertube

I'm quite new at biking and I got my first flat yesterday. I was able to remove the inner tube and patch it, thanks to a lot of youtube videos. But today I found the tire without pressure. And I found that the patch was leaking. I replaced the tube with my spare one. But I want to know if this is normal, for a patch, to last a few hours and then unstuck itself and let air pass?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Is this a traditional patch or self-adhesive? Did you follow all steps including the sandpaper? The traditional ones are supposed to be permanent and normally are.

Comment: I suggest checking where the tube leaks. Did you confirm the patch is loose? Isn't there a new hole? The tyre can contain a stuck sharp object.

Comment: Patch are Syncros glueless patch. They come with sandpaper:
https://www.syncros.com/se/sv/product/syn-glueless-patch-kit-pak-40.
And yes, I checked the inner tube, and the patch unstuck itself a little bit and the air pass through that. It's like a bubble formed from the innertube hole to the border of the patch.

Comment: As with housepainting, its all in the preparation.  Cleaning and buffing needs to be done right, as does locating the original source of the puncture lest it cause another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self adhesive patches are less reliable. I carry them (because they are so small) with my spare tube with my tubeless tyres to get home when the crap hits the fan but I witnessed some repeated struggle with some. I cannot comment your particular brand but my colleague had to re-apply some every 20 km or so.

I would use them to get home when the spare tube got punctured too. To permanently repair a tube use the traditional patches with a vulcanizing glue.

On my bikes that use inner tubes I carry the traditional patches. I want the reliability of those and have the space for them.

Comment: I typically carry two spare tubes.  Do enough mileage and Murphy will eventually strike.  My worst was 3 flats in 25 km, all unrelated.

Comment: @Criggie I would carry two spares for small road tyres and especially if I had inner tubes in my tyres already. With a tubeless setup and larger tubes there is no place for a second one, but one can often repair the hole with a worm if it did not seal in the first place. And with my secondary tubed MTB I had a puncture only once in thousands of km so a second spare is a luxury and the repair kit is enough in addition to one spare.

Comment: the number of spares carried should be related to the distance one might have to walk, worst case.

Comment: @Criggie Our country is quite civilized, but, more importantly, I trust the repair kit more than I trust a second spare. A second spare saves one more puncture and a repair kit saves more of them. If I know my rims. Once I had a rim that tend to cut valves, but that is exceptional and it was in the UK.